# wicket login is not working after upgrade tomcat 7 to 8

Tags: wicket, tomcat8, wicket-1.6

I am working on wicket version 1.4.17 in my application with tomcat 7.

After updating tomcat my application is broken.

The login page is not working when submit is clicked. It is working when I hit enter in the url.

If I click on the login button it is returning the same page, but if I login again then it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be related to Tomcat changing the session id after login.

Hard to tell whether your code or Wicket can't handle it, but 1.4.x is discontinued already.